# ElasticSearch return json exception

Tags: elasticsearch

```
public ResponseEntity findByContens(Integer page, Integer size, String[] split) {
  MultiSearchRequestBuilder multiSearchRequestBuilder = client.prepareMultiSearch();
  for (String key : split) {
    SearchRequestBuilder builder = client.prepareSearch()
          .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("attachment.content", key))
          .highlighter(new HighlightBuilder().preTags("<strong>").postTags("</strong>").field("attachment.content"))
          .setFrom(page).setSize(size);
    multiSearchRequestBuilder.add(builder);
  }
  MultiSearchResponse multiSearchResponse = multiSearchRequestBuilder.get();
  return ResponseEntity.ok(multiSearchResponse);}
```

It cause this exception:

> 2018-01-13 18:12:59.287  WARN 49204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: No serializer found for class org.elasticsearch.common.text.Text and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.elasticsearch.action.search.MultiSearchResponse["responses"]->org.elasticsearch.action.search.MultiSearchResponse$Item["response"]->org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse["hits"]->org.elasticsearch.search.SearchHits["hits"]->org.elasticsearch.search.SearchHit["highlightFields"]->java.util.Collections$SingletonMap["attachment.content"]->org.elasticsearch.search.fetch.subphase.highlight.HighlightField["fragments"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.elasticsearch.common.text.Text and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.elasticsearch.action.search.MultiSearchResponse["responses"]->org.elasticsearch.action.search.MultiSearchResponse$Item["response"]->org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse["hits"]->org.elasticsearch.search.SearchHits["hits"]->org.elasticsearch.search.SearchHit["highlightFields"]->java.util.Collections$SingletonMap["attachment.content"]->org.elasticsearch.search.fetch.subphase.highlight.HighlightField["fragments"])

How to solve this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No serializer found for class org.elasticsearch.common.text.Text

Wild guess (since there is not enough information to know for sure): You are using Elasticsearch 5.x or 6.x where analyzed fields are of the type `text`, but your Spring Data version is not 3.0 (which is the current version and required for Elasticsearch 5.x).

Either update Spring Data Elasticsearch to 3.x or if this is a transitive dependency from Spring Boot, you'll have to use the (soon to be released) version 2.0.